# Javascript : How to delete array if we have a collection of element's properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

consider we have an array like this

```
data = [
    {
        id:'1',
        foo:'foo'
    },
    {
        id:'2',
        foo:'foo'
    },
    {
        id:'3',
        foo:'foo'
    },
    {
        id:'4',
        foo:'foo'
    }

]
```

then we have some id of data to delete `id_delete = [2,4]`
i want to delete all matching id with the given id, in SQL we can do this by `delete from data where id in id_delete`, how to do this with javascript filter?

Comment: Do you want to modify the original array, or create a copy with the elements removed?

Comment: modify original array

Comment: If you want to modify the original array, *filter* is not the right tool, it creates a new array. If you want to delete elements of an array, you can use `array.splice(index, count)` which will also modify the array's length, or `delete array[index]` which will leave a missing element and keep length as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `filter`:

```js
const data = [{id:'1',foo:'foo'},{id:'2',foo:'foo'},{id:'3',foo:'foo'},{id:'4',foo:'foo'}];
const id_delete = [2, 4];

const res = data.filter(({ id }) => !id_delete.includes(+id));

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

To mutate the existing array, assign the result of `filter` to the `data` array, and use `let`.

```js
let data = [{id:'1',foo:'foo'},{id:'2',foo:'foo'},{id:'3',foo:'foo'},{id:'4',foo:'foo'}];
const id_delete = [2, 4];

data = data.filter(({ id }) => !id_delete.includes(+id));

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

If you want to fully *delete* each item, use `splice` with a backwards loop.

```js
let data = [{id:'1',foo:'foo'},{id:'2',foo:'foo'},{id:'3',foo:'foo'},{id:'4',foo:'foo'}];
const id_delete = [2, 4];

for (let i = data.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
  if (id_delete.includes(+data[i].id)) {
    data.splice(i, 1);
  }
}

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: why we place id inside curly bracket?

Comment: It's called destructuring @MatiusNugrohoAryanto - see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). It means we take the `id` property out of the object, instead of going `obj => obj.id`, we do `({ id }) => id`.

Comment: Assigning a new array to *data* does not "delete" the original array. If anything else references the old array, it will still reference the old array. To delete members from an array requires `array.splice(index, count)` or `delete array[index]`.

Comment: OK @RobG, I'll add that.

Comment: @JackBashford your `forEach()` method is not sufficient. Removing upvote until you provide a bug-free implementation using `splice()`.

Comment: What do you mean, "bug-free"? And "not sufficient"? I don't understand what more you would like @PatrickRoberts. That implementation *does* use `splice`.

Comment: Try changing `id_delete` to `[2, 3]` and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

To modify the array, use *splice* or *delete*. You can make a delete element function a little generic if it takes parameters for the array to modify, property to search on and value to match, e.g.

```js
let data = [{id:'1', foo:'foo'},
            {id:'2', foo:'bar'},
            {id:'3', foo:'fum'},
            {id:'4', foo:'fee'}
];

function deleteElementByPropAndValue(array, prop, value) {
  for (var i=array.length; i; ) {
    if (array[--i][prop] == value) {
      array.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
}

console.log(data);
deleteElementByPropAndValue(data, 'id', '3');
console.log(data);
deleteElementByPropAndValue(data, 'foo', 'fee');
console.log(data);
```

You should consider whether to use `==` or `===` in the equality comparison.

*splice* will shorten the array, hence working backwards through the indexes. You can also use `delete array[index]`, which will not shorten the array but will leave missing elements at the deleted indexes. That doesn't really matter if you use built–in methods to iterate over the array as mostly they skip missing elements, but some don't. And it may matter to other functions that don't expect sparse arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Using Ramda:

```
const data = [{id:'1',foo:'foo'},{id:'2',foo:'foo'},{id:'3',foo:'foo'},{id:'4',foo:'foo'}];
const id_delete = ['2', '4'];
const output = R.reject(item => R.contains(item.id, id_delete), data)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the `delete` operator from remove element of array based on position. To get the position of element you can use Array.findIndex if you wish remove only one element, else I suggest that you use Array.filter.
Also exists the Array.splice() to add/remove element of specific position from Array. Follows links about operator delete, splice and other very good about manipulation of arrays in JavaScript.

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/manipulating-arrays-in-javascript/amp/